# Changing the color of the active nav-item in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

I want to change the color of navbar text depending upon which page I'm browsing.

[Sample Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-active-18bg1)

For example if I'm on homepage, home icon should be in blue color.

[image]

Here is my `Menu.js` file

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Menu = () => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="row">
        <nav>
          <Link to="/home">
            <i className="fas fa-home"></i>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/search">
            <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/notifications">
            <i className="fas fa-bell"></i>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/messages">
            <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/profile">
            <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/signout">
            <i className="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
          </Link>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Menu);
```

I'm unable to find location of current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Router [Docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history)

> history objects typically have the following properties and methods:
> location - (object) The current location.
> May have the following properties: pathname - (string) The path of the URL

Updated csb [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-active-forked-ostc2)

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const activeTab = (history, path) => {
  if (history.location.pathname === path) {
    return { color: "#1fa2f1" };
  }
};

const Menu = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="row">
        <nav>
          <Link style={activeTab(history, "/")} to="/home">
            <i className="fas fa-home"></i>
          </Link>
          <Link style={activeTab(history, "/search")} to="/search">
            <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
          </Link>
          <Link
            style={activeTab(history, "/notifications")}
            to="/notifications"
          >
            <i className="fas fa-bell"></i>
          </Link>
          <Link style={activeTab(history, "/messages")} to="/messages">
            <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
          </Link>
          <Link  style={activeTab(history, "/profile")} to="/profile">
            <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
          </Link>
          <Link style={activeTab(history, "/signout")}to="/signout">
            <i className="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
          </Link>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Menu);
```

### Edit:

One advantage of using `history` over `NavLink` is that `Navlink` doesn't work for nested routes but `history` does.

For example:

"/profile/yogeshdecodes" - `Navlink` will make this route active state.

"/profile/yogeshdecodes" - `history` will not make this active state because `history` matches exact route.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the react-router documentation, you can use activeClassName to achieve this functionality.

Check out this [link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink)

Example

```
<NavLink to="/faq" activeClassName="selected">
  FAQs
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following what Adin said, here is the implementation:
https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-active-forked-6nep4

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link, withRouter, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Menu = () => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="row">
        <nav>
          <NavLink
            to="/home"
            activeStyle={{
              fontWeight: "bold",
              color: "blue"
            }}
          >
            <i className="fas fa-home"></i>
          </NavLink>
          <Link
            to="/search"
            activeStyle={{
              fontWeight: "bold",
              color: "blue"
            }}
          >
            <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
          </Link>
          <NavLink
            to="/notifications"
            activeStyle={{
              fontWeight: "bold",
              color: "blue"
            }}
          >
            <i className="fas fa-bell"></i>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/messages"
            activeStyle={{
              fontWeight: "bold",
              color: "blue"
            }}
          >
            <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/profile"
            activeStyle={{
              fontWeight: "bold",
              color: "blue"
            }}
          >
            <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/signout"
            activeStyle={{
              fontWeight: "bold",
              color: "blue"
            }}
          >
            <i className="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
          </NavLink>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Menu);
```

Comment: Although I solved my issue using `history` but I really appreciate your input and make me aware of `NavLink`.

Comment: You're welcome! Could you please accept the answer since it also solves the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but i was warking with `NavLink`, there is a props called `activeClassName` it detect when the `NavLinkis` active and apply style.

for exemple :

```
<NavLink to="/faq" activeClassName="selected">
  FAQs
</NavLink>
```

for more click [HERE](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using history props
`import { useHistory } from 'react-router';`

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';

var history = useHistory();

if (history.location.pathname == '<your route address>') {
   //your required code
}
```